# svelte : change variable value inside html block

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

```
<script>
    let count=0;
</script>

{#each list as item, i}
    <div class="item">
        <Item  />
    </div>
{/each}
```

How do I increment the count on some condition inside each block in svelte?

Answer (score 7):

You could use a [`{@const ...}`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-const) inside the block like so

```
<script>
    let count=0;
</script>

{#each list as item, i}
    {#if somecondition}
       {@const count=++count}

    <!-- and use it after maybe as Item prop -->
    <div class="item">
        <Item {count} />
    </div>
    {#else}
     <div class="item">
        <Item {count} />
    </div>
   {/if}
{/each}
```

Comment: Would be nice if we had @let as well.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to increment the actual `count` variable, you can do so in a callback defined in your `<script>` tag:

```html
<script>
    let count = 0;
    const increment = () => count++;
</script>

{#each list as item, i}
    <div class="item">
        <!-- Use increment() somewhere in here -->
        <Item />
    </div>
{/each}
```

If all you need to do is add some amount to `count` without mutating the original variable, you can just say so within braces:

```html
<script>
    let count = 0;
</script>

{#each list as item, i}
    <div class="item">
        {count + i}
        <Item />
    </div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you want it to reset and not keep the current state when the component re-renders so I would expand on Isaac Corbrey's answer.

```
<script>
    let count = 0;
    const reset = () => {count = 0; return "";}
    const increment = () => {count++; return count;}
</script>
{reset()}
{#each list as item, i}
    <div class="item">
        <Item count={increment()} />
    </div>
{/each}
```

Since the function reset doesn't return anything but an empty string in it's execution when the component re-renders it just resets the count to the default initial value and then increment returns the current value and can be used to pass it into the sub-component.

Comment: The crucial part here is `return ""`, which makes it so `undefined` isn't returned, and in turn rendered in th HTML

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue by calling a setter function inside the HTML like so:

```html
<script>
    let count=0;
    let incrementCount = () => {
      count++;
      return ""; //return empty string, so `undefined` isn't returned and in turn rendered in HTML
    }
</script>

{#each list as item, i}
    <div class="item">
        <Item  />
        {incrementCount()}
    </div>
{/each}
```

Edit: [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/1af47187b58d4f1bb237542523117085?version=3.53.1)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use JS within brackets, such as `{count + i}` or `{count + 1}`. Or wihtin the loop you could use a conditional statement like `{#if count > 1}`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: i tried all this but it does not work, i want to increment the count.

Comment: I have the same challenge. I want to set a boolean to false inside my html. But when I use {myboolean = false}, "false" is actually outputted as html text.

Comment: {myboolean=false,""}