# How to show header for grouped names in Svelte?

Tags: svelte-3

I'm currently using Svelte to show a list of names and I want to show a headline every time the name in the list changes, so the user has a clear view of the grouped names.

In this example I'm using the names `['Amber','Amber', 'Brian', 'Charlie','Charlie']`.

My expected output would be

```
<strong>Amber</strong><br>
Amber<br>
Amber<br>
<strong>Brian</strong><br>
Brian<br>
<strong>Charlie</strong><br>
Charlie<br>
Charlie<br>
```

I've put together a small snippet to show my problem;

```
<script>
let names = ['Amber','Amber', 'Brian', 'Charlie','Charlie'];
let currentName = '';

function setCurrentName(newName) {
    currentName = newName;
    return '';
}
</script>

{#each names as name}
<div>
    {#if (name != currentName)}
        <strong>{name}</strong><br>
        {setCurrentName(name)}
    {/if}
    {name}
</div>
{/each}
```

[Link to Svelte Repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/10eb94a652864ebd8e09c5d735deaa5b?version=3.57.0)

but the outputted list looks like this;

```
<strong>Amber</strong>
Amber
<strong>Amber</strong>
Amber
<strong>Brian</strong>
Brian
Charlie
Charlie
```

As you can see, we have 2 strong Ambers, one strong Brian and no strong Charlie.

- I'm using a callback function inside the loop, as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68393239/svelte-change-variable-value-inside-html-block).
- I have also tried to simply assign `currentName` to `name` by doing a `{currentName = name}`

My question now is;

**Why does Svelte behave like this and what can I do to fix it?**

Comment: If you put `{@debug name, currentName}` before the `{#if}` block and step through the program that way, you can see how it first generates the correct output, before it then goes through it a second time, producing the wrong output. Not sure what that shows, but it surely shows some weird behavior of svelte going through the list more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to fix this is to access the index in the each block (which allows directly accessing the previous element of the array) instead of updating the component's state inside the loop.

```
{#each names as name, i}
<div>
    {#if (name != names[i - 1])}
        <strong>{name}</strong><br/>
    {/if}
    {name}<br/>
</div>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know why svelte behaves like this, or even why it arrived at that point in the first place, as when you {@debug} it it seems to be generating the correct output at first.*

However, I managed to fix the behavior by putting the check into a function that also updates the value.

```html
<script>
    let names = ['Amber','Amber', 'Brian', 'Charlie','Charlie'];
    let currentName = '';
    function isCurrentName(name) {
        let result = currentName === name;
        currentName = name;
        return result;
    }
</script>

{#each names as name}
<div>
    {#if !isCurrentName(name)}
        <strong>{name}</strong><br>
    {/if}
    {name}
</div>
{/each}
```